# matplotlib axesgrid - additional colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add another colorbar to a plot where I use AxesGrid toolkit. For example, I add a colorbar axes using ImageGrid on the left, and then I add another one on the right manually. Here is a simple example:

```
f = plt.figure(1)
grid = ImageGrid(f, 111,  # similar to subplot(111)
                 nrows_ncols=(2, 2),
                 axes_pad=0.01,
                 add_all=True,
                 cbar_location="left",
                 label_mode='L',
                 cbar_mode="edge",
                 cbar_size="3%",
                 cbar_pad="2%",
                 )
for i in range(3):
    m = grid[i].matshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))
plt.colorbar(m, grid.cbar_axes[0])
m = grid[3].matshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)), cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar(m, shrink=0.5, anchor=(0, 0))
plt.show()
```

How do I make the new colorbar match the position of one of the subplots in the grid exactly? I at least managed to fix the size and y-position using shrink and anchor... But it also gets a bit complicated if I try to account for the padding between subplots, and if they are rectangular rather than square...

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. The sentence "make the new colorbar match the position of one of the subplots in the grid exactly" can be interpreted in many different ways. I think it would be better to clearly describe what is wrong with the plot you show. Are the left colorbars where you want them? Where would you like to have the right colorbar sit? To which positions do you want it to align? 'match exactly would imply that it has a square shape. Is this what you want? How many colorbars do you need in total?

Comment: I want to have the one colorbar on the left that I have. And I want to have another one on the right same way as the left one - aligned to one of the subplots. Not on top of it, as it is now, but next to it.

Comment: I don't think there is a good solution using AxesGrid, since it allows only subplots on one side of the plots. I suppose the reason you want to use AxesGrid is that you want to avoid spacings between the plots? But if you can drop the requirement of using an AxesGrid, a solution might be to use normal subplots.

Comment: Yes, without AxesGrid it becomes impossible to avoid spacing between subplots since I have fixed aspect ratios in all of them, and I have to adjust size of the figure to fix this... So using ImageGrid fixes this problem for me, but adding non-standard colorbars becomes difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to manually place the colorbar axes according to the position of one of the axes. To this end one first needs to draw the canvas, such that the positions are known. One can then create a new axes according to coordinates of image plot. This new axes will serve as the colorbar axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

fig = plt.figure(1)
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,  # similar to subplot(111)
                 nrows_ncols=(2, 2),
                 axes_pad=0.01,
                 add_all=True,
                 cbar_location="left",
                 label_mode='L',
                 cbar_mode="edge",
                 cbar_size="3%",
                 cbar_pad="2%",
                 )
for i in range(3):
    m = grid[i].matshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))
plt.colorbar(m, grid.cbar_axes[0])
m = grid[3].matshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)), cmap='plasma')

# first draw the figure, such that the axes are positionned
fig.canvas.draw()
#create new axes according to coordinates of image plot
trans = fig.transFigure.inverted()
g3 =grid[3].bbox.transformed(trans)
pos = [g3.x1 + g3.width*0.02, g3.y0, g3.width*0.03, g3.height ]
cax = fig.add_axes(pos) #l,b,w,h
# add colorbar to new axes
plt.colorbar(m, cax=cax)


plt.show()
```

[image]

This method depends on the position of the axes in the figure, once that changes, e.g. because the figure is rezised, unforseable things might happen.

A different method, which does not rely on the drawn coordinates, is to (mis)use inset axes and place the inset outside the axes. In this way the coordinates by which the inset is located are axes coordinates, so the colorbar will change its position according to the axes.

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

cax = inset_axes(grid[3], "3%", "100%", loc=3, bbox_to_anchor=(1.02,0,1,1), 
                 bbox_transform=grid[3].transAxes, borderpad=0.0)
plt.colorbar(m, cax=cax)
```

Comment: Thank you! So basically the addition of the axes for the colorbar should be the last thing to do, in case something changes the layout of the figure?

Comment: I found a potentially better way, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just found the inset_axes myself and was experimenting with it! I'll try it now.