# When does matplotlib update axis bboxes, and can an update be forced?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When creating axes in a figure, the bounding box (`bbox`) is changed at some point during plotting.  I'd like to have access to the final `bbox` values (e.g., through `ax.get_position()`) while running a non-interactive script.  How can I force the `bbox` values to update *without* triggering a plot-to-screen (e.g., using `pl.pause`)?

A minimum example is below, showing that the `bbox` is updated if a sequence of commands is called interactively from the ipython command line, but the `bbox` is *not* updated if used in a script (in this case, `%paste`d):

```
In [1]: import pylab as pl

In [2]: fig = pl.figure()

In [3]: ax = fig.gca()

In [4]: print(ax.get_position())
Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.9, y1=0.88)

In [5]:

In [5]: im = ax.imshow([[0,1],[1,0]])

In [6]: print(ax.get_position())
Bbox(x0=0.22375000000000006, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.80125, y1=0.88)

In [7]:

In [7]: cb = fig.colorbar(mappable=im)

In [8]: print(ax.get_position())
Bbox(x0=0.1675000000000002, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.7450000000000001, y1=0.88)

In [9]: %paste
import pylab as pl
fig = pl.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
print(ax.get_position())

im = ax.imshow([[0,1],[1,0]])
print(ax.get_position())

cb = fig.colorbar(mappable=im)
print(ax.get_position())
## -- End pasted text --
Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.9, y1=0.88)
Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.9, y1=0.88)
Bbox(x0=0.125, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.7450000000000001, y1=0.88)

In [10]: print(ax.get_position())
Bbox(x0=0.1675000000000002, y0=0.10999999999999999, x1=0.7450000000000001, y1=0.88)
```

My main use case is setting a colorbar's location *without* using the `axes_grid` toolkit, since that changes the size of the parent axis too.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43319537/4124317) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45634754/4124317).